# Android closed Alpha track is not showing to invited users when Beta is available. Beta is showing instead?

Tags: android, google-play, release, alpha

I have uploaded a new version to the closed Alpha track in play store, added testers and published. I have gotten the opt-in URL and have joined as a tester. Everything seems fine until I go to the app in play store. Here only the old Beta version is available and I cannot find any traces of Alpha anywhere. The app has been published in aprox. 12 hours when writing this. I have not received any mail or notification yet.

I have used the open Beta track a lot before and never had problems with this (did not need to wait for long before it was available). Do I need to wait even more, disable Beta or do something else?

Note: Alpha and Beta have the same opt-in URL...

[image: Test groups selected]

[image: Play store overview]

[image: Google play screenshot]

Comment: I've experienced the same, on the playstore app it shows you the "highest level" you have access to. So if you are in the alpha & the beta it'll show you the beta

Comment: Hmm, this seems strange since the Beta is lower version number and build number, but okay. How can I "remove" the Beta version so the Alpha will become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced the same, on the playstore app it shows you the "highest level" you have access to. So if you are in the alpha & the beta it'll show you the beta.

Therefore remove the invite to the Beta version, and they should be able to see the alpha version.

Note that this is in the playstore app, from the web you can direct link to each track.

Comment: I could not find the separate apps in browser either, but this method worked for me. Strange behaviour since the Alpha track was higher version and build number...